# Expression to describe group visibility in RDLC report?

Tags: expression, visibility, rdlc

I have such a case where a Text Box's visibility is dependent on a row group's visibility (let's say the group is called GroupA). Actually this Text Box is showing the title of this row group, so only if the row group is visible, this text box would appear. I guess I can achieve this by setting the visibility of this text box using an expression. However, I don't know how to express the GroupA's visibility in expression. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter to the report expressing if the GroupA is visible, then use this parameter to set the textbox visibility.

Post an example of your code... or explain the logic that shows/hides the GroupA.

If the logic is the presence of records then the you can do this check outside the report, inside the code, and pass this information as parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am having a pivot report, which means I want the user to toggle on/off some items. 
For example, if I am making an employee number report, in the out-most row group (GroupA) I am grouping data based on their Working Department, so the rows might say Sales 100, next row says Market 100. And in the inner row group I am grouping them based on location, and the visibility of this can be toggled by user. So at initialization there is only Sales 100, in the first report row. But when the user clicks "Sales" cell, the inner group is expanded,

Comment: like US 50, Europe 30, Asia 20 (sum is 100). I know how to make such pivot report now. Now my problem is, I want to show the Titles on the top of the report (Department, Location, ...). The "Department" should always be there since it is the initial criteria, but I only want to show "Location" when the user toggles the location group on. And this I don't know how to do

Comment: The hide/show of the sections is impemented on the client side using RDLC code? In other words: you hide/show without postbacks?

Comment: What do you mean by postback? I set the visibility of the row-group by changing the property of it. Under "Visibility", there is this checkbox "Display can be toggled by this report item" and the droplist to select the item which user clicks to hide/show (I am using VS2010). This is a local report, and no values passed back to any function if that's what you are asking. Thanks!